# mpi appplication is unable to connect to the smpd manager on (null):55846 error 1722

Tags: c++, mpi

using `Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK` and `Microsoft SDK 9`

code (ReadText.cpp):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "before mpi init\n";
    cout.flush();

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    cout << "after mpi init\n";
    cout.flush();

    MPI_Finalize();
    cout << "after mpi finit\n";
    cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

after running the command line:

```
mpiexec -n 1 ReadText.exe
```

got the output:

```
before mpi init

Aborting: mpi appplication on LAPTOP-TL0C61UH is unable to connect to the smpd manager on (null):56041 error 1722

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Init(argc_p=0x00CFFA1C, argv_p=0x00CFFA08) failed
```

when running `mpiexec` with `-debug` got this output : https://justpaste.it/2elu1

can't find over the internet helpfull information to solve this issue...

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return from mpi_init?

Comment: Output belongs *in* the question. Not behind links to external sites. Please try to make the question self-contained.

Comment: I know that I have to check the mpi_init return. But as you can see by output, mpi_init just exits the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same error as yours. The thing i was done, is uninstall the Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK and Microsoft SDK 9. And installed the Microsoft MPI v10.1.2 with its SDk.

You can find it [Here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100593)